# Prevent infinite call to setState in React Class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, redux, state

I have a React class component with the following code (only included the relevant stuff):

```
class SomePage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      stuff: ""
    }
  }

  // NOTE: this.props.data comes from mapStateToProps from below

  componentDidMount() {
     console.log(this.props.data)   // shows up as "undefined"
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(this.props.data);   // has the data I need

    if((prevProps.data !== this.props.data) && this.props.data.part1 && this.props.data.part2) {  // LINE A
      console.log("inside if statement");     // never entered
      this.setState({stuff: this.props.data.part2});      // need to set state here!!
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      {this.state.stuff}
    )
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
       data: state.analysisReducer.data;
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SomePage);
```

If I change the `componentDidUpdate` from above to not include `prevProps` in the if statement, as shown below, then the `setState` is called infinitely.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log(this.props.data);   // has the data I need

  if(this.props.data && this.props.data.part1 && this.props.data.part2) {                 // LINE B - removed the "prevProps.data !=="
    this.setState({stuff: this.props.data.part2});  // entered, but called infinitely
  }
}
```

***Problem***: As shown above, **Line A** is never entered and the setState in **Line B** causes an infinite loop.

***Goal***: I need to call the `setState` only once, either when I get access `this.props.data` once its data becomes available or when the `this.props.data` changes from the its previous state.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifing the data props that you are passing so you don't need to put that in components state. You can skip all the state stuff and just use the props that you are passing.

// Added after comment
You are still not editing the data passed from props, but here is an example of how to do what you want with a functional component.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <input type='text' value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <Page data={{ part2: input }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Page = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    setState({
      ...state,
      stuff: props.data.part2
    });
  }, [props.data.part2]);

  return <div>{state.stuff}</div>;
};
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-varahamihira-bgqpby

Comment: Thanks for your input. I actually DO need to access this.props.data but oversimplified my code in the question. I've edited the code in the question to so that it's slightly more detailed. Please check that - thank you.

Comment: @penguin i added an working example of what you want to do. But I still don't see why you need the state in the component. Anyways have a look and see if it helps you.

Comment: You've changed my code to something new - from a class component to a functional component, you've removed the redux entirely, and added elements I'm not using. This is cool and I appreciate the time and effort you put into this, but I don't think this solves my problem! I'm just looking for an edit to the existing code I have.